# Make listview with checkboxes act like checkbox list

Tags: vb.net, listview, checkbox, checkboxlist

I need a checkbox list that I can add read-only items (hence using a listview so I can gray-out an item and keep a user from selecting it).

However, when I click the item, the checkbox doesn't toggle. But when I add the following code to the item click event,

```
Private Sub LVSubFiles_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LVSubFiles.Click
        If LVSubFiles.Items(LVSubFiles.FocusedItem.Index).ForeColor <> Drawing.Color.Gray Then
            If LVSubFiles.Items(LVSubFiles.FocusedItem.Index).Checked = True Then
                LVSubFiles.Items(LVSubFiles.FocusedItem.Index).Checked = False
            Else
                LVSubFiles.Items(LVSubFiles.FocusedItem.Index).Checked = True
            End If
        End If
End Sub
```

But in this case when the user clicks on the checkbox rather than the item, nothing happens, as well selecting any other checkbox checks both the highlighted item and the checkbox of the new item selected.

Is there a way I can make the items act like a checkbox list? I've tried using Data Grid View, but i run into similar issues and a lot of code is based on the actions of this listview.

Comment: Take a look at the `itemChecked` event and [ask] and the [tour]

Comment: All items in a `ListView` are read-only. Do you actually mean that you want some items selectable and some not?

Comment: My appologies, what I meant by read-only was i need to grey-out some items that shouldn't be selectable. I can't grey out an item in a checkboxlist. I'm thinking the big issue is that a checkboxlist only has one selectable item per line whereas the listview has the checkbox as a separate entity. I was hoping there was a way to unify them so that there wouldn't be this disassociation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who find this question. I ultimately went with a hidden column which tracked "read only" items. Whenever the list would update the read-only tags would turn the item gray, but still enable it to be checked.

In regard to how the list interacted with the user, I moved the action items into the two categories and this seems to be working smoothly. The user can select/deselect with a single click regardless of which part of the item is clicked.

```
Private Sub dgvSubFiles_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvSubFiles.CellContentClick
    If dgvSubFiles(dgvSubFiles.Columns("chkSubFiles").Index, dgvSubFiles.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Value = True Then
        dgvSubFiles(dgvSubFiles.Columns("chkSubFiles").Index, dgvSubFiles.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Value = False
    Else
        dgvSubFiles(dgvSubFiles.Columns("chkSubFiles").Index, dgvSubFiles.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Value = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub dgvSubFiles_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dgvSubFiles.SelectionChanged
    dgvSubFiles.ClearSelection()
End Sub
```